# Entity Framework extending multiple UserType from ApplicationUser using Inheritance Mapping

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm creating a Course Management app so in the app, there are two main user types which are `Lecturer` and `Student`. For the user manager task, I decided to use Identity Framework. I do know to extend a custome `ApplicationUser` from `IdentityUser` and probably know how to extend multiple other user type from `ApplicationUser` using `inheritance mapping` as well. However, in the `ApplicationDbContext` I'm stuck on how to configure the data table so `Lecturer`, `Student` and `ApplicationUser` will be stored in just one table `AspNetUser` in Entity database.

This is my `ApplicationUser` which was customized from `IdentityUser`

```
    public class ApplicationUser: IdentityUser
    {       
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public byte[] ProfilePicture { get; set; }
    }
```

And `Lecturer`, `Student` derived from `ApplictionUser`

```
    public class Lecturer: ApplicationUser 
    {
       // some properties
    }

    public class Student: ApplicationUser
    {
      // some properties
    }
```

This is my `ApplicationDbContext` configuration

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
        {
            // To modify the default ugly names of the Identity Tables, add this override function,
            base.OnModelCreating(builder);
            // set schema to the database 
            builder.HasDefaultSchema("Identity");
            // all of the lines below to rename table 
            builder.Entity<IdentityUser>(entity =>
            {
                entity.ToTable(name: "User");
            });

            // CAN I DO DO LIKE THIS???
            builder.Entity<Lecturer>();
            builder.Entity<Student>();


            builder.Entity<IdentityRole>(entity =>
            {
                entity.ToTable(name: "Role");
            });

            builder.Entity<IdentityUserRole<string>>(entity =>
            {
                entity.ToTable(name: "UserRoles");
            });

            builder.Entity<IdentityUserClaim<string>>(entity =>
            {
                entity.ToTable(name: "UserClaims");
            });

            builder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin<string>>(entity =>
            {
                entity.ToTable(name: "UserLogins");
            });

            builder.Entity<IdentityRoleClaim<string>>(entity =>
            {
                entity.ToTable(name: "RoleClaims");
            });

            builder.Entity<IdentityUserToken<string>>(entity =>
            {
                entity.ToTable(name: "UserTokens");
            });
        }
```

Comment: In your particular case, a property named `UserType` on `ApplicationUser` might be a better option instead of extending empty classes.

Comment: @MatJ Could you provide more information of that way?

Comment: See EF Core docs on inheritance which outlines the exact use case you have: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/inheritance#table-per-hierarchy-and-discriminator-configuration

Comment: @abdusco yeah, the configuration is the same. But `ApplicationUser` is derived from `IdentityUser` so can I do the same as the configuration in the article you provided? Sorry If the question is dangling, I just confused at that point.

Comment: @KeinKeinKein You need to add a discriminator to differentiate rows in a table that belong to different types.

Comment: @abdusco How to map multiple `base userType` together and add `discriminator` in DbContext? As I know If use EF code first, it will create column `Discriminator` automatically for me?

Answer (score 1):

The best way to store those to `AspNetUsers` table is to check whether there is a column called **Role** in the table. Probably it's there. So in the column, all the roles should be assigned like student, lecturer or others as well.

```
public class ApplicationUser: IdentityUser
{       
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Role { get; set; } //Add this property to the class
    public byte[] ProfilePicture { get; set; }
}
```

It would be more feasible or maintainable to manipulate those roles using the approach

Comment: Thank you for commenting. I got your idea but how can I configure to map those models as columns in `AspNetUsers`? table in `ApplicationDbContext`. The confusing part is `ApplicationUser` is derived from `IdentityUser` .

Comment: You require to create a model that matches the `AspNetUsers` table. Otherwise it'll throw exception in the entity level. Try defining exact properties to the class you create.

Answer (score 0):

It would be more proper to **configure** that in the **OnModelCreating method** while **adding DbSet properties** to the DbContext **for the derived classes**.

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }
    public DbSet<Lecturer> Lecturers { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Student> Students { get; set; }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
       ... ...
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You *shouldn't* derive Student and Lecturer from `ApplicationUser`. In Microsoft Identity those are roles. So, when you create the migration, and apply it to the database, you will see `AspNetUsers`, `AspNetRoles`, and `AspNetUserRole` tables. In other words, there is many-to-many relationship between Users and Roles (in your case it is unlikely that any user will be in both Lecturer and Student roles; but you can imagine scenario where this *would* be required).

So, I recommend you rethink your design and then feel free to ask additional questions.

Also, you don't need to do anything complex in your DbContext. Specifically, I don't see anything in your question that would require to write your own `OnModelCreating()` Just make sure you specify `AppUser`:

```
public partial class YourDbContext : IdentityDbContext<AppUser>
{
    public YourDbContext (DbContextOptions<YourDbContext > options) : base(options)
    {
    }
    public DbSet<AppUser> AppUsers { get; set; }
}
```

Happy coding!